# Count percentages on poll with PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I am working on poll system and i want to count percentages of how many time this variant has been chosen.
  For example  i have got 4 available variants

```
Poll name | Vote number  
  Java    |     250
  Python  |     200
  C#      |      90
  PHP     |      1
```

There 3 columns in my `Polls` db `Id,Tex,Creator_id`
And there 4 columns in `Poll_variants` my db of questions which are

```
Id | Poll_id | Variant | Vote_num
1  |    1    |  Java   | 250 
1  |    1    |  Python | 200 
1  |    1    |  C#     | 90 
1  |    1    |  PHP    | 1
```

Comment: @GurV i added what your spirit wished

Comment: @user7302801 can show us what is your desired output should be??

Comment: @GurV could i satisfy thy spirit this time?

Comment: @reza `Java-46%`,`Python-36%`,`C#-16%`,`php-0.1%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find total of votes for each poll_id in a subquery and join it with the main table to find the percentage of each variant.

```
select t1.*, 100 * t1.votes/t2.total_votes percentage
from Poll_variants t1
inner join (
  select poll_id, sum(votes) total_votes
  from Poll_variants
  group by poll_id
) t2 on t1.poll_id = t2.poll_id;
```

Comment: Can you explain t1 and t2?My mysql knowledge boundaries stop at `Join` function

Comment: t1 and t2 are aliases for your_table and the subquery respectively. We use them so that we don't have to write like `your_table.some_column` everywhere

Comment: so t1 is my table for polls or questions?

Comment: It's neither - It's another name for the actual table name. I've updated my answer by changing `your_table` to `questions`

Comment: I tried this code and unfortunately it return new column with `NULL` in it

Comment: which column please? and what are the values of other columns?

Comment: I've just now tried the query with your given sample data and it's working perfectly. I got the same percentages you posted in the comment above

Comment: Thanks for the code but because reza's code was simple i had to accept his answer.Thanks again for your heuristic answer.May good be with ye!

Comment: @user7302801 Tell me this - are there going to be many poll_ids? do you want to find percentage in each poll? If yes, then the answer you accepted  is terribly wrong.

Comment: Maximum 10 for each poll.Poll numbers will depend on user number.Yes i want to find percentage for each poll.Why is it terrible?

Comment: Because it is wrong as it's finding total on all the polls. My query is complex but correct. Because it find total in each poll and then uses it to find the percentage.

Comment: You are very right.After testing it i found mistake in it too.Thanks for informing me about mistake.

Comment: Just one more question please,if i want to select only where `Creator_id` is say 1 how can i do that?

Comment: join do a join with poll table and where condition with creator_id  = something

Answer (score 0):

You can use following SQL

```
SELECT *,Votes*100/(SELECT sum(Votes) from Poll_variants)total FROM Poll_variants WHERE 1
```

Comment: What is `count*100`?

Comment: This code return new column `total` with `NULL` value

Comment: did you changed the table name in my code before tring??. i have updated my query with your table name now. is it still returning null??